# how do i fix Parallel Stacks window?

Tags: visual-studio

I have VS 2019 Enterprise. When I open Parallel stacks, I see a loading message.

[image]

Comment: How many do you have?

Comment: how many what ? apples ? trees ?

Comment: I am guessing MSFT has a VS bug (fail)

Comment: I meant how many threads do you have? (Can you see them in the threads window?)

Comment: earlier , the parallel stacks had about 10 entries in the async logical stack windows. 
now i see a empty nothing .
I am using the tasks view . I work at MS , otherwise I would use a better tool.

Comment: Well, I do _not_ work at MS, but I doubt there exists a better debugger than VS.